# How to pass variable from express view to router.js file - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hogan.js

I collecting information on my view via javascript and an onclick event, however the only way I see to pass back as a response is the below.

```
window.open("/explorer/" + e.target.id , "_self" );
```

Then in the router file index.js file I use the follow to get that param and use it in my node code.

```
router.get('/explorer/:folder_name, function(req,res) {
        var command = 'ls -lrt ' + req.params.folder_name;
        exec(command);
    }
});
```

This does work, but the problem is that the router file then tried to open a page that doesn't exist.

This is a simple process, but I can't seem to find a simple way to do this.

Any suggestions on how to pass a var from an express view eg.. index.hjs to router file eg.. index.js in node.js express?

Comment: i would suggest you to read about html links, forms and forms. and some expressjs documentation also you never ever ever excute lines from the client at least w/o previous sanitazion

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon Are you suggesting using a POST to the backend? I know about html links and forms, however I don't think they present a solution in this situation. If you know of one, I would be interested in hearing it. Obviously this is a POC without validation in place.

Comment: why do you think a form won't do it? what issue do you find in that approach?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon If I was to post from view, how would I receive that data in the backend? I have attempted this with app.post, but had no luck.

Comment: the same way you always do a view is juts a web page you speify an action in the form pointing to your route , seriously read about forms and web apps lifecycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you have returned a response from the request. Could it be trying to find a 404 or 500 page that's not found?  If you send a response like below does it resolve the problem?

```
res.send({ status: 'success' });
```

**Update:**

Per your comment here is a contrived example on sending data from the client (view) to the express router:

```
$.post('/explorer', 'folder=' + e.target.id);
```

On the server you can set up a route handler like so to handle the request:

```
router.post('/explorer', function(req, res) {
    var command = 'ls -lrt ' + req.body.folder;
    exec(command);
});
```

This code has not been validated, so you may have to tinker with it.

Comment: Can I user res.send in my view? would that be inside a script tag? How could I recieved that at the backend?

Comment: It sounds like you might need more communication between the client/server.  In that case I recommend a few google searches for posting data to expressjs using jQuery.

Comment: Your answer is how to send from backend to view, if you could provide an example of how this can be used for the reverse that would be great. I have spent quite some time reading and looking for a solution online before posting this question.